# How to Stop App on Package Name change?

Tags: android, android-activity

I need to implement a function where if the Package name of the App is changed, the App will stop i.e. `this.finish();`

But it isn't working, here is the code I am Using -

```
public void chk(){
      String ucci = getApplicationContext().getPackageName();
        if (ucci!=("my.package.name")) 
            {
       //do nothing
                }
                else {
                    this.finish();
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Name Changed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
                }
}
```

& then I use it in onCreate like `this.chk();` but doesn't work

Comment: it not work. first think package name can not change and second think is if package name change then you call getApplicationContext().getPackageName();  it will give package name from manifest.

Comment: it can change if you use an App Cloning App

Comment: @DarShan I see you've unaccepted my answer. Is there a problem with it?

Comment: @Aryan sry, happened by mistake :P

Comment: No probs. Happy Coding :)

Comment: @Aryan can u help on dis - https://stackoverflow.com/q/47736791/6819340

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logically if package name is equal to `"my.package.name"` then `finish()` called otherwise nothing happen.

Please use `!ucci.equals("my.package.name")` instead of `!=`.

`==` and `!=` work on object identity. While the two Strings have the same value, they are actually two different objects.