# DialogFragment's width takes the whole screen unlike AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-layout, android-dialogfragment, android-dialog

I am trying to inflate a CustomView in my dialogFragment class, it works fine but the width takes the whole screen (90%) but if I inflate the same layout in AlertDialog, it just Works fine i.e width seems proper & good.

I also tried setting the DialogFragment's width via onStart() but it wasn't the desired result...

This is what I want (CustomView in AlertDialog)
[image: 1]

but here's the Result via DialogFragment -
more width is taken as compared to AlertDialog!
[image: 2]]

Layout File -

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/lz_gridChooserParent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.lazygeniouz.colorpicker.FillGridView
            android:id="@+id/lz_grid"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:columnWidth="@dimen/colorchooser_circlesize"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:horizontalSpacing="8dp"
            android:numColumns="auto_fit"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
            android:verticalSpacing="8dp"
            android:padding="16dp"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left|bottom"
                android:text="Custom"
                android:id="@+id/lz_gotoCustom"
                android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:typeface="serif"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
                android:text="@string/back"
                android:id="@+id/lz_back"
                android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:typeface="serif"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"
                android:text="@string/done"
                android:id="@+id/lz_done"
                android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:typeface="serif"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>

        </FrameLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: try to give width and height on onresume

Comment: @ManojFrekzz i have given width to match_parent & wrap_content in the onStart().... setting width to wrap_content shrinks the dialog

Answer (score 2):

If you are planning to run this application on a fixed size devices than it is ok, but if your application will run on different size devices (phones of different screen sizes or tablets) than consider applying match_parent on your fragment container, and apply layout padding from parent container with the proportion of empty space you need to surround your fragment.

This will let you control the size of your fragment and at the same time will allow smooth resizing in case of different screen sizes.

For example, if you inflate your activity layout from XML file that contains linear layout root element and a fragment child element, the padding is applied on linear layout element and the match_parent will be for the fragment element. in such case you choose a relevant padding figures  that will let you achieve your targets.

I hope this provide some useful implementation ideas to you.

Answer (score 1):

try what worked by me:

my class is extends AlertDialog instead of DialogFragment,

and inside the class I override show function as follows:

```
 @Override
    public void show() {
        super.show();
        getWindow().setLayout(500, 300);
```

and then i open it like this:

```
MyDialog myDialog = new MyDialog(getActivity());
                myDialog.show();
```

hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

this is what I did,
I just set the DialogFragment's width to 520 & it gave me exactly what I wanted :)